# ContentDocument is not workin in vba

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

1. `object.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(0).contentDocument.getElementById("ID").Value ="abc"`
2. `object.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(0).document.getElementById("ID").Value ="abc"`

When I use two codes mentioned above, it shows the error message "NULL REFERENCE"

But when I use 3rd code which is mentioned below, it is running fine.

3. `object.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(0).Document.getElementById("ID").Value ="abc"`

But in this case when I write it in macro, then "Document" becomes "document" and shows the null reference error.

```
object.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(0).Document.getElementById("ID").Value ="abc"
```

becomes to

```
object.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(0).document.getElementById("ID").Value ="abc"
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the url/relevant html? Ideally the url.

Comment: if you have working code what is the problem? Do you simply want to know why contentDocument syntax doesn't work in this context?

Comment: the code object.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(0).Document.getElementById("ID").Value ="abc"  work in console but when it is written in vba macro, it changes to object.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(0).document.getElementById("ID").Value ="abc" (Note the "document" after (0) is in small letters) automatically and gives a "NULL REFERENCE" Error. How to solve it and use it in a vba macro?